# Receive remote notification when iOS device is locked and I'm not responding immediately

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app is receiving remote notifications (APNS) and is working for all the common scenarios:

- App is not running (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
- App is running and active (didReceiveRemoteNotification:)
- App is running, the phone is locked and I unlock the device as soon as I get the notification (didReceiveRemoteNotification:)

However, not if I in the last case choose not to unlock the device immediately (with the slider) and I wait until the screen goes black again. The message/notification is still shown in the lock screen, but the slider can now only unlock the device and when I do, didReceiveRemoteNotification: doesn't get called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid this is the intended behaviour. Quote the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/), part *Scheduling, Registering, and Handling Notifications*:

> If the action button is tapped (…), the system launches the
>   application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method (…); it passes in
>   the notification payload (…). If the application icon is tapped (…),
>   the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information
>   about the notification.